# Copying files from a GParted live session doesn't show them properly on Windows

Tags: boot, partitioning, live-usb, filesystem, gparted

I recently asked [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/427169/cant-install-try-ubuntu-after-dd-sda-hard-drive?noredirect=1&lq=1). You might read it to see what problems I'm experimenting, but it's not needed.

The thing is, I booted my computer from a live session of GParted, and I'm able to see both of my partitions, `sda1`, and `sda2`, which contain important data I'd like to save.

Since I can see this data from the live session, I connected another USB to my laptop, I mounted this USB, and passed around 5Gb of this important data to the newly inserted USB. I thought that this would save the data, and that then I would be able to wipe the disk and reinstall Ubuntu, but sadly, when I insert the USB with the important data to my Windows computer, I'm not able to open the data, I see the [following picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGtgR.png).

I think that this is because of using different file systems, but I'm not sure, since this problem doesn't happen when using a normal Ubuntu instead of a live session of GParted.

When I try to manipulate the data from the live session, I can do it without any problems.

The problem here is that I can't wipe the disk if I don't know if the data copied to the USB will be accessible from the new Ubuntu, and I don't have any other Ubuntu machine to check if the data is correctly accessible.

Is my assumption right? Will I be able to see and use the files in the USB if I wipe the disk and install Ubuntu from zero? What other method can I use to save these files?

Please note that I can't open a live session of Ubuntu, only one of GParted.

Comment: What kind of filesystem is on the USB? It might not be compatible with Windows. Try formatting the USB in windows before copying the files in gparted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is that gparted doesn't copy files, it copies partitons -- raw data sector by sector.

Thus if you are going to copy data  from an ext partition and paste it into an ntfs partition, you will end up with a bunch or garbage since the two file systems are radically different.

You need to copy to idendical file systems or use cloning software, such as clonezilla.